# Extraer path y método de un objeto (swagger) a un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, object, swagger

Tengo el siguiente objeto swagger object que contiene los siguientes datos. Es el resultado de sacar por consola:

```
console.log(swaggerExpress.runner.swagger);

{ swagger: '2.0',
  info: { version: '0.0.1', title: 'My API' },
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  basePath: '/api/v1',
  schemes: [ 'http', 'https' ],
  consumes: [ 'application/json' ],
  produces: [ 'application/json' ],
  paths:
   { '/login': { 'x-swagger-router-controller': 'auth', post: [Object] },
     '/profile':
      { 'x-swagger-router-controller': 'auth',
        get: [Object],
        patch: [Object] },
     '/groups/types/{groupId}':
      { 'x-swagger-router-controller': 'groups',
        get: [Object],
        patch: [Object],
        delete: [Object] },
     '/products':
      { 'x-swagger-router-controller': 'products',
        get: [Object],
        post: [Object] },
     '/products/{productId}':
      { 'x-swagger-router-controller': 'products',
        patch: [Object],
        delete: [Object],
        get: [Object] } },
  definitions:
   { ErrorResponse: { required: [Array], properties: [Object] },
     Profile: { required: [Array], properties: [Object] },
     Token: { required: [Array], properties: [Object] },
     LoginData: { required: [Array], properties: [Object] },
     Group: { required: [Array], properties: [Object] },
     GroupList: { type: 'array', items: [Object] },
     Product: { properties: [Object] } } }
```

Lo que espero, es convertirlo en un array de objetos como el siguiente:

```
[{url: '/products', method:'GET'},{url: '/products', method:'POST'}...]
```

En caso de que una misma ruta tenga distintos métodos (get,post,delete...), lo debería separar en varios objetos, uno por cáda método aunque las rutas se repitan.

No sé ni por dónde empezar con este tipo de objeto devuelto, agradezco cualquier ayuda porque es la primera vez que trabajo con Nodejs, swagger...

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una posible solución iterando sobre las keys de `paths` con `Object.keys(obj.paths)` luego, dentro del `.reduce()` iteramos las propiedades con un `for..in` y las vamos poniendo en un array:

```js
const obj = {"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"0.0.1","title":"My API"},"host":"localhost:3000","basePath":"/api/v1","schemes":["http","https"],"consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json"],"paths":{"/login":{"x-swagger-router-controller":"auth","post":[null]},"/profile":{"x-swagger-router-controller":"auth","get":[null],"patch":[null]},"/groups/types/{groupId}":{"x-swagger-router-controller":"groups","get":[null],"patch":[null],"delete":[null]},"/products":{"x-swagger-router-controller":"products","get":[null],"post":[null]},"/products/{productId}":{"x-swagger-router-controller":"products","patch":[null],"delete":[null],"get":[null]}},"definitions":{"ErrorResponse":{"required":[null],"properties":[null]},"Profile":{"required":[null],"properties":[null]},"Token":{"required":[null],"properties":[null]},"LoginData":{"required":[null],"properties":[null]},"Group":{"required":[null],"properties":[null]},"GroupList":{"type":"array","items":[null]},"Product":{"properties":[null]}}};

//Suponiendo que quieres excluír algunos metodos
const metodosExcluidos = ['x-swagger-router-controller', 'patch'];

const res = Object.keys(obj.paths).reduce((p, c) => {
    for (let prop in obj.paths[c]) {
        if (!metodosExcluidos.includes(prop)) {//< -- sacar si no quieres excluír ningun método
            p.push({ url: c, method: prop.toUpperCase() });
        }
    }
    return p;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

En el ejemplo estoy excluyendo algunas propiedades solo a modo de ejemplo.